# queuing async operations?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, asynchronous, queue

I'm using a c# COM library that provides an async mechanism (actually it is PDFCreator, imposed by my customer). 
Converting a doc file to a PDF file requires two things :

- a `PrintFile` method that starts the conversion
- a `ready` event to indicates the conversion is finished

*[Edit] : There is not the Begin/End methods of the async patterns. I have to start the printfile method, and wait for the event to be raised*

this is OK when I have only one file to convert, but I'm struggling with batch conversion of several files because of this async pattern.

How can I manage a queue of files to convert ?

I'd like my application (a WPF one) simply "enqueue" a file to convert.... Then my worker object dequeue files one by one, ensuring only one conversion at a time can occurs.

Please note that I'm using C# 4, and I'd like (because I'm learning) to use Tasks if it's an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDFCreator exposes an APM based interface (i.e BeginFoo / EndFoo methods) then you can wrap those methods within a Task:

```
Task<int> bytesRead = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync( 
    stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
```

there is an article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx which eplains this in more detail.

Once you have a group of tasks can you start them queue them via a custom TaskScheduler or the default one:
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx), it looks as though you can use the default task scheduler in your scenario.

```
task.Start()
```

Note: if you want to have these tasks notify the UI when they finish, you could use a continuation, (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) which can notify the UI when the task has finished. Note to marshall back to the UI thread you'll need to use a a SynchronizationContext or Dispatch.BeginInvoke.

Comment: unfortunately, PDFCreator OM (COM interop) only provides a "Setup" method (which includes the output filename :(), a start method and a event to tells it's finished. The proper Begin/End pattern is not available (Or maybe I an encapsulate it) ?